# Why does the behaviour of my program change just based on maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, xpath, classpath, classloader

So this is the code I have:

```
package biz.tugay.deleteNow;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 19/12/15 Time: 12:57 */

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException, FileNotFoundException {
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String expression = "/library/catalog/book";
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
        inputSource.setCharacterStream(new FileReader(new File("/Users/koraytugay/Desktop/widgets.xml")));
        Object evaluate = xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        DTMNodeList dtmNodeList = (DTMNodeList) evaluate;
        System.out.println(dtmNodeList.getLength());
    }
}
```

and here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>biz.tugay</groupId>
    <artifactId>deleteNow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>deleteNow</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <finalName>deleteNow</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and lets give it a try:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:deleteNow koraytugay$ mvn clean install
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Korays-MacBook-Pro:deleteNow koraytugay$ cd target
Korays-MacBook-Pro:target koraytugay$ java -cp deleteNow-jar-with-dependencies.jar biz.tugay.deleteNow.TestClass
12
```

Ok, all seems fine, now I will add a dependency in my pom.xml and repeat the whole process..

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

build successful, try to execute:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:target koraytugay$ java -cp deleteNow-jar-with-dependencies.jar biz.tugay.deleteNow.TestClass
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList cannot be cast to com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList
    at biz.tugay.deleteNow.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:22)
```

Why is this happening? How can a dependency break a working software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of your **dependency** to a **specific implementation of an Interface**.

```
 import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList;
```

This line causes the error. By importing Xalan, you activate a different XPath provider wich in turn creates `org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList` instead of `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList`

If you would change your code to use `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` instead, both XPath implementations would work **with both**:

```
    Object evaluate = xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList dtmNodeList = (NodeList) evaluate;
    System.out.println(dtmNodeList.getLength());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what do you mean "you activate a different XPath provider" ? How / when does the process know what to return? How is it determined?

Comment: In xalan-2.7.2.jar/META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory contains value org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl which replaced the default JDK implementation to this one.

Comment: I don't know the implementation details - but once Xalan is visible on the classpath, the XPathFactory will return instances of Xalan's XPathFacotryImpl and with them all of Xalan's XPath implementation instead of the default JDK implementation. Now I know, thanks to @LaszloHirdi

Comment: @LaszloHirdi Thank you for the comment. Could you give me pointers or more details? Who is responsible for this replacement and where does it take place, and why?

Comment: Please see javadoc of 'public static final XPathFactory newInstance(String uri) throws XPathFactoryConfigurationException' for the 4 step algorithm how class loader finds the class XPathFactoryImpl: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html#newInstance(java.lang.String)